# kerasでの画像認識が終了しない

Tags: python, keras

https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/04/28/110000
を拝見し，実際にソース，使用した画像をそのまま流用して実行しました．
しかし，1エポックが終了する時になっても次のエポックに移行ない問題が発生しました．
CPUなどを見ても動作してるようには思えるのですが一向に移行しません．
考えられる問題などは何がありますか？

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D,                     GlobalAveragePooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, LearningRateScheduler, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.regularizers import l2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy.misc import imresize
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
import math

K.clear_session()
img_size=299
#訓練データ拡張
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        rotation_range=10,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=False,
        zoom_range=[.8, 1],
        channel_shift_range=30,
        fill_mode='reflect')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

#画像の読み込み
def load_images(root,nb_img):
    all_imgs = []
    all_classes = []

    for i in range(nb_img):
        img_name = "%s/dog.%d.jpg" % (root, i + 1)
        img_arr = mpimg.imread(img_name)
        resize_img_ar = imresize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size))
        all_imgs.append(resize_img_ar)
        all_classes.append(0)
    for i in range(nb_img):
        img_name = "%s/cat.%d.jpg" % (root, i + 1)
        img_arr = mpimg.imread(img_name)
        resize_img_ar = imresize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size))
        all_imgs.append(resize_img_ar)
        all_classes.append(1)
    return np.array(all_imgs), np.array(all_classes)

X_train, y_train = load_images('./train', 1000)
X_test, y_test = load_images('./train', 400)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, seed = 13)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_test, y_test, batch_size=64, seed = 13)

#Inception v3モデルの読み込み。最終層は読み込まない
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
#最終層の設定
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(1, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="sigmoid", kernel_regularizer=l2(.0005))(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

#base_modelはweightsを更新しない
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

opt = SGD(lr=.01, momentum=.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
csv_logger = CSVLogger('model.log')

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                  patience=5, min_lr=0.001)

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=2000,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=test_generator,
                    validation_steps=800,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr, csv_logger, checkpointer])
```

追記
1エポックが終了する時と判断したのは，次のように出力された状態で止まるためです．
ここから一向に処理が進まないにも関わらず（1エポック終了時に作成するhdf5ファイルなども作成されない），CPUなどはしっかり動いています．

```
Epoch 1/2
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 264s - loss: 0.7831 - acc: 0.6094
2/5 [===========>..................] - ETA: 154s - loss: 0.7622 - acc: 0.5859
3/5 [=================>............] - ETA: 85s - loss: 0.7396 - acc: 0.5729 
4/5 [=======================>......] - ETA: 38s - loss: 0.7270 - acc: 0.5703
```

Comment: どのようにして「1エポックが終了する時になった」と判断なさったのですか？

Comment: 本文に追記しましたとおり，最後の手前のステップまでで止まってしまいます．

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/91452

Answer (score 1):

[マルチポスト先](https://teratail.com/questions/91452)の [sayaka1202 さん](https://teratail.com/users/sayaka1202)の投稿によると

```
epochs = 3
batch_size = 64
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
```

とした上で fit_generator を適宜変更すると上手くいったようです。

Answer (score 0):

私がKerasとtensorflowを使ってを使って学習させた際は、数十秒でエポックの終わりまで逹し、そこから40分ほど表示が止まってから次のエポックに処理が移っていました。
学習はただのデスクトップマシンで行なったので、単に性能が低いためだろうと思っていました。
単に処理が重いため時間がかかっているだけなのでは？
参考にされたサイトではAWSのインスタンスを使っているようですが、同じ環境で動かしているのですか？
CPUなどが稼動しているなら処理が止まっているわけではなさそうですが...